# I have a problem whith adding a Container in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am a student in informatics and beginning in Java, I want to create a project which will allow me to make a calculator.

I am encountering a problem which is the following: I want to add Container in my JFrame with add(contenu), but it gives me the following warning :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    adding container's parent to itself
```

I don't understand why this problem appears.

Here are the class codes of my project:

class Main :

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Fenetre fen = new Fenetre();
        fen.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

class Fenetre :

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    public JButton boutonsNombre[];
    private static int nChiffres = 10;

    public Fenetre() {
        setTitle("CALCULATRICE");
        setSize(1700, 900);
        Container contenu = getContentPane();
        contenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(contenu);
        boutonsNombre = new JButton[nChiffres];
        for (int k = 0; k < nChiffres; k++) {
            boutonsNombre[k] = new JButton(String.valueOf(k+1));
            contenu.add(boutonsNombre[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Have you any idea about why this problem appears?

Comment: You're adding the ContentPane to itself. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments already mentions you are trying to add the JFrame's content pane to itself.

The following will work:

```
public Fenetre() {
        setTitle("CALCULATRICE");
        setSize(1700, 900);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        boutonsNombre = new JButton[nChiffres];
        for (int k = 0; k < nChiffres; k++) {
            boutonsNombre[k] = new JButton(String.valueOf(k+1));
            this.add(boutonsNombre[k]);
        }
    }
```